# Visibility of a base class constructor in a derived template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem to compile the following code, it simply results in a compile error, see below.

What I did not understand:
If my class `Any` itself is not a template class, all works as expected. ( you can uncomment the example code lines to this.

If `Any` is a template the `BASE_T` is not longer visible. Is there a trick to make it visible again?

Why I need the `BASE_T`? As you can see ConcatHelper template creates a class from all types which are part of the variadic list of this template. Real world code did some more but doesn't matter for this example here. I defined my `BASE_T` to reduce my code and must not copy all the template parameters again and again.

Used compilers: g++5.3.1 and latest snapshot of gcc6.

```
#include <iostream>

class F {};  

template<typename T>
class FReader
{   
    public:
        FReader(F&){}
};  

template<typename T> class A { };
template<typename T> class B { };


template < typename FILETYPE, typename Base, typename ...Tail> class ConcatHelper;

template <typename FILETYPE, typename Base, typename Head, typename ...Tail>
class ConcatHelper< FILETYPE, Base, Head, Tail...>: public Head, public ConcatHelper< FILETYPE, Base, Tail... >
{   
    public:
        typedef ConcatHelper< FILETYPE, Base, Head, Tail...> BASES_T;

        ConcatHelper(FILETYPE &_is): ConcatHelper< FILETYPE, Base, Tail... >(_is){}
};  

template<typename FILETYPE, typename Base>
class ConcatHelper<FILETYPE, Base>: public Base
{   
    public:
    ConcatHelper(FILETYPE& _i): Base(_i){}
};  

//class OUTER_MASTER{};
template <typename OUTER_MASTER>
class Any: public ConcatHelper<F, FReader<OUTER_MASTER>, A<OUTER_MASTER>,B<OUTER_MASTER>>
{   
    public:
        Any( F& is): BASES_T ( is ) {} // did not compile
        //Any( F& is):ConcatHelper<F, FReader<OUTER_MASTER>, A<OUTER_MASTER>,B<OUTER_MASTER>>(is) {} // compiles
};  

int main()
{   
    F f;
    Any<int> gr(f);
    //Any gr(f);

}
```

results in:

```
error: class 'Any<OUTER_MASTER>' does not have any field named 'BASES_T'
```

if I change:

```
Any( F& is): BASES_T ( is ) {}
```

to

```
Any( F& is): std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type::BASES_T ( is ) {}
```

But is this really valid c++ code?

Comment: This does compile on MSVC, but not on Clang or GCC. A bug or undocumented feature perhaps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a typename from a template derived class you need to qualify used type name.

As the C++ standards says (14.6.2/3):

> In the definition of a class template or a member of a class template,
>   if a base class of the class template depends on a template-parameter,
>   the base class scope **is not examined during unqualified name lookup**
>   either at the point of definition of the class template or member or
>   during an instantiation of the class template or member.

Qualifying the constructor with class name works:

```
template <typename OUTER_MASTER>
class Any: public ConcatHelper<F, FReader<OUTER_MASTER>, A<OUTER_MASTER>,B<OUTER_MASTER>>
{   
    public:
        Any( F& is): Any::BASES_T(is) {}
};
```

Comment: Ups, this is the definite simplified variant of my workaround :-) Thanks! Something the world is much easier as we thought about!